# JQuery BlockUI Dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, blockui

I'd like to use blockUI to block the page when an item is selected from the dropdown list (asp:Dropdownlist).  The UI does get "blocked" when an item is selected (onchange event), but stays blocked.  It seems like the postback event is not getting fired. I'm able to block and unblock UI when I click on the button that does postback to the server, processes what it needs to and comes back and unblocks the page.  I'm not able to get it to do the same from dropdown list.  any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var URL;

    function showWaitPanel(msg) {
        $.blockUI({
            message: '<p>' + msg + '</p>'
            ,css: {
                border: 'none',
                padding: '15px',
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                opacity: .5,
                color: '#fff' }
        });
    }

    function removeWaitPanel(msg, url) {
        $.unblockUI();

        if (msg != '') {
            $.blockUI({ message: '' + msg + '' });
            setTimeout($.unblockUI, 20000);
        }

        if (url != '')
            window.location.href = url;
    }

</script>
```

```
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVendors" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlVendors_SelectedIndexChanged"  >
```

....

On server side, codebehind,...
Page_Load(...)
{

```
       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlVendors.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return showWaitPanel('Please Wait...');");
    }
```

}

```
    protected void ddlVendors_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        .....
        RemoveWaitPanel("ddlVendors_SelectedIndexChanged", "", "");
    }

    private void RemoveWaitPanel(string key, string message, string url)
    {
        string strScript = "return removeWaitPanel('" + message + "', '" + url + "');";

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), key, strScript, true);

    }
```

showWaitPanel() on client side does get executed when an Item is selected , UI is blocked but then server side ddlVendors_SelectedIndexChanged (postback) doesn't get executed

Comment: First suggestion is *share your code*..

Comment: @MichalKlouda.. Michal updated original post with the code.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing it all client side. As an example, you are looking at the ajax call. 
Can you look at another event that happens before?   
Like:

1. Show Loading Indicator
2. Block UI
3. Ajax Call
4. Hide Loading Indicator (we have data back from our web method)
5. Unblock UI.